# Why is ∆ not a valid identifier in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, identifier

According to [this](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers), JavaScript allows Unicode characters as identifiers. However, this is how Node handles it.

```
  > var ∆ = 6;
  > ...
```

I've also put it in the [identifier validator](http://mothereff.in/js-variables), and it agrees that "∆" shouldn't be allowed.

I suppose my question is "What's so special about ∆?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That isn't [U+0394 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA](http://codepoints.net/U+0394); it's [U+2206 INCREMENT](http://codepoints.net/U+2206), which is a Math Symbol, not a Letter.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript identifiers can contain any "Unicode Letter", which means

> any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.

Now, what you *can* do is this:

```
var \u0394 = 0;
```

and `0394` is the Unicode value for ∆.  Clearly, that's not quite as satisfying, but it is syntactically OK.

*edit* — as usual SLaks is correct; you can in fact do this:

```
var Δ = 0;
```

when you've got the right version of Δ. (In my current font the math version is prettier.)

Comment: If `var \u0394;` works that means the unescaped version of that identifier works too. Read [the post you’re quoting from](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) for more info, or [see this Stack Overflow answer for the TL;DR](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/96656).

Comment: @MathiasBynens yes that became clear once I saw what SLaks had figured out :)